# Bluetooth Soft Serial and PS2 controller on Arduino Leonardo

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, software-serial, playstation2

I am trying to combine two input sources that are recognized as a single gamepad/controller. For that purpose, I am using an Arduino Leonardo that can be easily transformed into an HID device using the `Joystick.h` library. As inputs, I am using (1) a PS2 Controller with the PS2x library and (2) Bluetooth serial data coming from an HC-05 working in master mode.

I have built a separate sketch to read and parse the Bluetooth data, and even managed to forward it via the `Joystick.h` library to the PC.

At the same time, in order to use the PS2 controller, I have linked the PS2 to USB using the same Arduino Leonardo. However, when I tried to combine these two sketches (to combine two inputs from BT and PS2), something does not work.

I figured out that PS2_lib used for reading values from PS2 controller prevents Arduino from reading BTSerial data or vise-versa.

Here is the sketch, when `ReadOneByte()` is called, nothing works.

```
byte ReadOneByte() {
  int ByteRead;
  while(!BTSerial.available());
  ByteRead = BTSerial.read();
  return ByteRead;
}
```

If I comment out the while loop, the PS2 and gamepad works.

The full sketch:

```
#include <PS2X_lib.h>  //for v1.6
#include "Joystick.h"
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>


Joystick_ Joystick(JOYSTICK_DEFAULT_REPORT_ID, JOYSTICK_TYPE_GAMEPAD,
    12, 2, // Button Count, Hat Switch Count
    true, true, true, // X and Y, but no Z Axis
    false, false, true, // No Rx, Ry, or Rz
    false, false, // No rudder or throttle
    false, false, false);  // No accelerator, brake, or steering

#define PS2_DAT        3  //14    
#define PS2_CMD        2  //15
#define PS2_SEL        12  //16
#define PS2_CLK        13  //17

//#define pressures true
#define pressures false
//#define rumble true
#define rumble false

const bool testAutoSendMode = false;
SoftwareSerial BTSerial(11, 10);
PS2X ps2x;

int error = 0;
byte type = 0;
byte vibrate = 0;

void setup() {
  SoftwareSerial BTSerial(11, 10);
  BTSerial.begin(57600);
  Serial.begin(57600);
  delay(300);
  Joystick.begin();
  //setup pins and settings: GamePad(clock, command, attention, data, Pressures?, Rumble?) check for error
  error = ps2x.config_gamepad(PS2_CLK, PS2_CMD, PS2_SEL, PS2_DAT, true, false);
  type = ps2x.readType();
  Joystick.setXAxisRange(0, 255);
  Joystick.setZAxisRange(0, 255);
  Joystick.setYAxisRange(0, 255);
  Joystick.setRzAxisRange(0, 255);
}

byte ReadOneByte() {
  int ByteRead;
  while (!BTSerial.available());
  ByteRead = BTSerial.read();
  return ByteRead;
}

void loop() {
  ReadOneByte() ;
  // Always be getting fresh data
  if (error == 1) //skip loop if no controller found
    return;
  error = ps2x.config_gamepad(PS2_CLK, PS2_CMD, PS2_SEL, PS2_DAT, pressures, rumble);
  ps2x.read_gamepad(false, 0);
  Joystick.setButton(0, ps2x.Button(PSB_TRIANGLE));
  Joystick.setButton(1, ps2x.Button(PSB_CIRCLE));
  Joystick.setButton(2, ps2x.Button(PSB_CROSS));
  Joystick.setButton(3, ps2x.Button(PSB_SQUARE));
  Joystick.setButton(4, ps2x.Button(PSB_L2));
  Joystick.setButton(5, ps2x.Button(PSB_R2));
  Joystick.setButton(6, ps2x.Button(PSB_L1));
  Joystick.setButton(7, ps2x.Button(PSB_R1));
  Joystick.setButton(8, ps2x.Button(PSB_SELECT));
  Joystick.setButton(9, ps2x.Button(PSB_START));
  Joystick.setButton(10, ps2x.Button(PSB_L3));
  Joystick.setButton(11, ps2x.Button(PSB_R3));
  Joystick.setXAxis(ps2x.Analog(PSS_LX));
  Joystick.setYAxis(ps2x.Analog(PSS_LY));
  Joystick.setZAxis(ps2x.Analog(PSS_RY));
  Joystick.setRzAxis(ps2x.Analog(PSS_RX));
  if (ps2x.Button(PSB_PAD_UP)) { //will be TRUE as long as button is pressed
    Joystick.setYAxis(0);
  }
  if (ps2x.Button(PSB_PAD_RIGHT)) {
    Joystick.setXAxis(255);
  }
  if (ps2x.Button(PSB_PAD_LEFT)) {
    Joystick.setXAxis(0);
  }
  if (ps2x.Button(PSB_PAD_DOWN)) {
    Joystick.setYAxis(255);
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a lot of trouble to do the same as the [scpToolkit](https://github.com/nefarius/ScpToolkit)

Comment: Well, I don't know about scpToolkit, but I need BT connection too, where I receive some biofeedback data. The device (hardware) needs to be portable and work plug&play virtually with any PC as HID Gamepad/Joystick

Comment: I figured out that both Joystick.setButton(bttn,boolean) and ps2x.Button(button) are resource demanding, thus when none of the buttons were pressed, a lot of "release" commands have been passing through creating a lot of overhead and computational demands. As result of this overhead, the loop() cycle has been slowed down, preventing serial data from Bluetooth to be read properly. I solved this problem by setting a boolean variable (e.g. xButtonReleased), so I call only respective commands when it is necessary.